# Splitting legend in QGIS in to 2 columns

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, mapping, column

I am new to QGIS and I am making a map of India showing some quantity. I added the legend to my map layout, I have 10 symbols in my legend and it is very long , so I wish to split it into 2 columns. I tried it using the column option in legend properties. But when I increased the column number to 2 and apply the changes into my legend, only half part of the legend is seen. The second part is get cropped. Anybody please help to split the legend into 2 and show both halfs. I will add the screenshot below.

[image: The screenshot of lengthy legend]

The changes when I tried to split into 2 ,I highlighted how I tried to change into 2 columns
[image]

Comment: You need to make the legend box wider to display 2 columns

Answer (score 6):

Resize your legend box to make your content "flows" in the 2nd column e.g the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: & lan Turton , your suggestion worked. No wit correctly split into 2 columns. Thank you